# How to set up Google Apps (mail) MX Records on DNSMadeEasy (screen shot included)

Tags: email, mx-record

I am attempting to complete google's mail MX setup. I would link, but new users can't have two links, and I think the following img is more important.

This is what my input options are for DNS Made Easy, which manages my domain:

[image]

I would like to confirm that I understand the fields correctly. It is my understanding that I am supposed to:

1. Leave Name (Host) Blank
2. Set Data to ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM. (and repeat for each of the server addresses provided by google)
3. Set the MX level to what Google has in "Priority" column
4. Set TTL as high as possible

Did I get it right? The nightmare scenario is that I screw up, and bring everyone's mail down :P

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost Perfect. The TTL shouldn't be "as high as possible" though because if you need to modify your dns in the future you don't want everyone to have to wait days to repropopgate. A few hours is fine.

Comment: If you're uncertain of the changes being made, then it's better to use something like 5 minutes, both before and after; set it before, for the duration of your previous TTL, so that all behaving clients have the new 5 minute TTL.

This way, if you need to revert, you're down for maybe seven minutes total; not great, but not a disaster, with mail senders typically retrying after 10-15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you pretty much got it right.

You could leave the TTL value relatively low for starters if you want to. TTL is "Time To Live", which is the amount of time that a DNS server/client is supposed to cache the result of the lookup. If you set it low to begin with then at least if you need to change it, it won't take long for the rest of the DNS world to see the change.

Answer (score 0):

- Server: aspmx.l.google.com. MX Level: 1 TTL: 7200
- Server: alt1.aspmx.l.google.com. MX Level: 5 TTL: 7200
- Server: alt2.aspmx.l.google.com. MX Level: 5 TTL: 7200
- Server: aspmx2.googlemail.com. MX Level: 10 TTL: 7200
- Server: aspmx3.googlemail.com. MX Level: 10 TTL: 7200

I would recommend setting MX Level (priorities) to that of the above. I learned it the hard way.